# EOF and BOF error when querying SQL database

Tags: sql, vbscript

I'm trying to query a SQL database from vbs but when no record is found I get an error

> ADODB.Field : Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record.

I think I need to use an IF NOT statement to capture if the record isn't found but I can't figure out where it needs to go.

```
Do Until objFile.AtEndofStream
    strAppName = objFile.ReadLine

    ConnString="DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=aardvark002;UID=***;PWD=***;DATABASE=DEW_Users"
    SQL = "USE Win7AppData SELECT " & Chr(34) & strCountry & Chr(34) & " FROM AppsByCountry WHERE Application = '" & strAppName & "'"

    Set Connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set Recordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Connection.Open ConnString
    Recordset.Open SQL,Connection
    strApproval = Recordset(strCountry)
    If StrApproval = "YES" Then
        strApproval = "Approved"
    Else
        strApproval = "Denied"
    End If
    objExcel.Cells(intRow, 1).Value = strAppname 
    objExcel.Cells(intRow, 2).Value = strCountry
    objExcel.Cells(intRow, 3).Value = strApproval
    intRow = intRow + 1
Loop
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bit rusty on my VBScript, but you should be able to use .EOF on the Recordset to check if it's at the end:

```vb
Recordset.Open SQL,Connection
If Recordset.EOF = false Then
    ' have some rows, do what you want with them
End If
```

[W3Schools reference](http://www.w3schools.com/ado/prop_rs_bofeof.asp)

Comment: +1 When using ADODB, the .EOF reference on it's own is enough, you would only need to combine .BOF & .EOF when working with DAO in MS Access for example.

Answer (score 1):

I was checking the `Recodset.EOF` and `Recordset.BOF` to make sure that both are False, but everytime I was receiving the mentioned error. That took me some hours but I finally realized that if you call the `Recordset.Fields.count` the `EOF` and `BOF` are changed to `True`.

I hope this can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could have another bug also in case you have more than one record as result, then you need to move your recordpointer if you don't want to end in an endless loop, i also shortened your code a bit, on the other hand you need to close your connection if you'r not going to use it again.

```vb
ConnString="DRIVER={SQL  Server};SERVER=aardvark002;UID=***;PWD=***;DATABASE=DEW_Users"
Set Connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Connection.Open ConnString
Do Until objFile.AtEndofStream
  strAppName = objFile.ReadLine
  SQL = "USE Win7AppData SELECT " & Chr(34) & strCountry & Chr(34) & " FROM AppsByCountry WHERE Application = '" & strAppName & "'"
  Set Recordset = Connection.Execute(SQL)
  Do While not Recordset.EOF 
    strApproval = Recordset(strCountry)
    If StrApproval = "YES" Then
      strApproval = "Approved"
    Else
      strApproval = "Denied"
    End If
    objExcel.Cells(intRow, 1).Value = strAppname 
    objExcel.Cells(intRow, 2).Value = strCountry
    objExcel.Cells(intRow, 3).Value = strApproval
    intRow = intRow + 1
    Recordset.MoveNext
  End If
Loop
Connection.Close
Set Connection = nothing
```